# Update node's pod capacity

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to figure out how to update a node's pod capacity. I have a simple cluster setup using the Vagrant/VM environment outlined in the documentation. I have attempted to patch the node's pod capacity using kubectl doing the following:

Sending just JSON needed for patch via:

```
kubectl patch node 10.245.1.3 -p '{"status": {"capacity": {"pods": "4"}}}'
```

and

```
kubectl patch node 10.245.1.3 -p "`cat node.json`"
```

Where node.json is the nodes JSON from a GET request except with pods change to 4 and the resourceVersion attribute removed.

The command seems to be accepted because the node's resourceVersion number changes. However, the capacity of pods does not. Any ideas?

I am using Kubernetes 1.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeStatus is a subresource that is periodically updated by the node (kubelet) itself, and the capacity is calculated based on available resources (cpu, mem, etc) on the node. Updating the Node object does not update the status.

If you want to set a maximum capacity of a node, you can pass a [flag to the kubelet](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/54706661ad72d62ea0b494112a74e0467093c9f4/cmd/kubelet/app/server.go#L317) during startup. This would require you to restart kubelet though.

Comment: Thanks. I found that flag. However, I can't figure out how to restart the kubelet though. I found [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9cfab87e33ea649bdd13a1bd243c502d76e5d22/cluster/centos/node/scripts/kubelet.sh) and figured out how to stop the service but where do I update that flag. I tried updating it when restarting the service but that gives and error.

Comment: What cloud/os are you using and how did you create your cluster? The exact answer depends on your specific setup. In general, you have to update a script or salt config and does a node upgrade. E.g., if you use `cluster/kube-up.sh` with salt, you can update the [salt configuration here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/saltbase/salt/kubelet/default). The node upgrade document is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/cluster-management.md#node-upgrades).

Comment: I am just running locally using virtualbox per the instructions outlined [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant.html) Based of the [file](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9cfab87e33ea649bdd13a1bd243c502d76e5d22/cluster/centos/node/scripts/kubelet.sh) I linked previously I am sshing into minion-1 and running:     systemctl stop kubelet KUBELET_ARGS="--max-pods=10" systemctl start kubelet  However, this doesn't appear to update max-pods either.

Comment: Updating comment with better code formatting: I am just running locally using virtualbox per the instructions outlined [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant.html) Based of the [file](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9cfab87e33ea649bdd13a1bd243c502d76e5d22/cluster/centos/node/scripts/kubelet.sh) I linked previously I am sshing into minion-1 and running: `$ systemctl stop kubelet` then: `$ KUBELET_ARGS="--max-pods=10"` and then: `$ systemctl start kubelet` However, this doesn't appear to update max-pods either.

Comment: Add --max-pods=10 to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service` and then run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart kubelet`

Comment: That did it! Thank you!